# Export to glTF with PBR materials ( facebook integration)

Tags: node-editor, export, pbr, gltf

I'm experimenting with [3D posts on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/3d-posts) on the only supported format is binary glTF. I'm using the [Khronos exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) and their [PBR node groups](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/tree/master/pbr_node).
Has anyone been able to export a model with PBR and display it on facebook?
I get:

- the model without my PBR material when I use the Metallic Roughness node tree
- an "GLB File Invalid" error from facebook when I use the Specular Glossy node tree

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing good to use the PBR node inside Blendere but include the textures (make them internal), then save the .blend file.

THEN export to .GLB, it should work. Relative path issues mess the drag-drop on Facebook post.

Comment: don't forget to mark texture relative path (included) when exporting.

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks so much!

Comment: In Blender 2.8+ you can use a Principled BSDF node instead of the custom node groups.